# How can I relate multiple ids to a single row in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am working on a personal library database in MS SQL Server 2014 and I have two tables called Book, and Genre. The Genre table has a list of genres that a book can have. How can I let a book have multiple Genres with out repeating my attributes because each book might have a different number of Genres?

```
<Genre> 
ID | Name

<Book>
ID | Title | AuthorID | GenreID | GenreID2 | GenreID3 | ... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Cross Reference table.  The table might look like this:

```
  <BookGenre>
  GenreId | BookId
```

For each genre that applies to a book, you insert a record into this table with the appropriate GenreId and BookId.

Comment: Duh of course. Thank you, I just drew a blank here.